# Webhook validation handshake failed

Tags: azure, azure-eventgrid, azure-logic-app-standard

i'm new in azure and wanted to create an Event subscription to push any changes (here resource write success) from my blob storage to my Logic App via HTTP. In my Logic app i have a *When a HTTP request is received*, which would run when i send a request.

just wanted to demonstrate how i'm trying to create it.

NAME: 'i dont think this matters'

...

TOPIC NAME: 'just gave it a Random Name, should this refer to sth?'

Source Resource:'My Storage Account'

ENDPOINT:'i got the URL from the Overview page of my logic app (Workflow URL
)'
URL looks like this:

```
https://LOGICAPPNAME.azurewebsites.net:443/api/APPNAME/triggers/manual/invoke?api-version=2022-05-01&sp=%2Ftriggers%2Fmanual%2Frun&sv=1.0&sig=RjVKZbs-0CV559hZYlFfhM0k22W39lS5
```

when i copy and paste this to my browser i can trigger my Logic App. i think that act as a GET and i'm not sure if it sends it as POST or etc. it would make any difference.

[image]

and i got this error.

> Deployment has failed with the following error: {"code":"Url validation","message":"Webhook validation handshake failed for https://LOGICAPPNAME.azurewebsites.net/api/APPNAME/triggers/manual/invoke. Http POST request retuned 2XX response with response body . When a validation request is accepted without validation code in the response body, Http GET is expected on the validation url included in the validation event(within 10 minutes). For troublehooting, visit https://aka.ms/esvalidation. Activity id:ID, timestamp: DATE TIME"}

If there's still confusion on how i'm doing this, i'm trying to follow [THIS EXAMPLE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/544349/34when-blob-is-added-or-modified34-trigger-will-no.html). How can i fix this Error?

Comment: this sounds similar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69708472/create-an-eventgrid-subscription-to-a-standard-logic-app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reproducing from my end, I could able to achieve this following the link you have provided using the below details for creation of my logic app.

[image]

The reason you are receiving that error is that you need to use Logic App HTTP Trigger Request URL as Web Hook's endpoint and not the Logicapp's URL.

**NOTE:** You don't really have to call the Trigger again, whenever you make any changes to your storage account the logic apps gets triggered.

**RESULTS:**

1. **When Blob is Created**

   [image]
2. **When a Blob is Deleted**

   [image]

***REFERENCES:*** ["When blob is added or modified" trigger will not be fired on subfolder" answered by SamaraSoucy-MSFT - Microsoft Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/544349/34when-blob-is-added-or-modified34-trigger-will-no.html)

Comment: I also made the same mistake and didn't use the whole long URL that must be copied from the Designer in the Logic App from the first HTTP Post action.